# Issue with CPU and memory being consumed after a segue between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

I am having an issue with using my segue to go between two different scenes on a collision.

My code currently will wait for a collision of sprites, then it will run:

```
func gameOver() {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("gameOver", sender: nil)
}
```

which as you can tell performs a segue (modal) to the gameOver scene which is a ViewController with a UIImageView and a "RETRY" button which then uses a modal segue to go back to GameViewController and my game runs again until a collision.

The issue is that every time a collision is detected and I hit "RETRY", I can see more and more memory and CPU being used up on the monitor. I also see a loss of about 30FPS after around the 8-10th retry.

My Collision function is:

```
func collision(Bee:SKSpriteNode, Player:SKSpriteNode) {
    scene?.paused = true
    println("HIT")
    self.viewController.gameOver()
}
```

I believe the issue might be related to the `scene?.paused = true` but I have tried everything and just can't figure out a proper way to dismiss the scene when a collision is detected, and restart the whole game when "RETRY" is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you were using a modal segue to go back to a new game? I think the problem is that you will be creating a new version of the game controller. Hence why your memory is going up. Each time its a new game controller added.

When retry is hit, why not just dismiss the retry controller so it reveals the original game screen.

So either dismiss the RETRY controller or use a reverse segue which is the mechanism for segueing backwards.

Inside the action for the RETRY button just add:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Okay i'll try this! That appears to be in objective-c rather than swift right? How would I do this in swift?

If I dismiss the retry controller, how can I restart the gameController so the game actually starts again? I assume it will dismiss the view I am in and go back to the collided state of the game

Comment: `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Thanks I just figured it out before you posted. As expected, the game now just starts where it collided. All objects have stopped moving too. Do you know how I could 'restart' the gameScene?

Comment: I would add some code in viewDidAppear. This will get called when your view controller comes back as the main view. In there restart the game. NB: It also gets called the first time your controller appears. As a guess, call: `scene?.paused = false`. Not sure how your code works.

Comment: I think I answered the question 8^). You are on to new questions now.

Comment: Okay thanks I have copied my code from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear and besides an unpleasant 1 second pause before the game starts again, it seems to be working fine now except for the timer which just keeps counting up and isn't restarting.

Answer (score 0):

you need to invalidate your timer at the end of the game this will stop the timer.

```
nametimer.invalidate()
```